# AsyncTask and custom CursorAdaper

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-cursoradapter

I'm in some trouble with custom cursorAdapter and AsyncTask. I wanted to setup listView and adapter first and after that in asyctask to query data from database. But for a first time cursor in adapter is null and it throws an a exception. How can be handled this such on situation in my custom cursor adapter? Relocation of setAdapter to onPostExecute didn't helped also. Any suggestions will be also great.

Main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ConversationsListCursorAdapter conversationsListCursorAdapter = new ConversationsListCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.conversations_list_item, null, 0);
    conversationsListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    conversationsListView.setAdapter(conversationsListCursorAdapter);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new GetConversationsTask().execute((Object[]) null);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Cursor cursor = conversationsListCursorAdapter.getCursor();
    if (cursor != null) { 
        cursor.close();
    }

    conversationsListCursorAdapter.changeCursor(null);
    super.onStop();
}

private class GetConversationsTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params) {
        Uri uri = ClouContentProvider.CONVERSATIONS_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor = null;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        } else {
            CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context, uri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        }

        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
        conversationsListCursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Cursor adapter:

```
public class ConversationsListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private final Cursor mCursor;
    private final Context mContext;
    private final int mLayout;
    private final int mSnippetIndex;
    private final int mDateIndex;
    private final int mMessageCount;
    private final int mRead;
    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    //private static final String TAG = ConversationsListCursorAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvBody;
        TextView tvPerson;
        TextView tvCount;
        TextView tvDate;
        QuickContactBadge ivPhoto;
        View vRead;
    }

    public ConversationsListCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);

        this.mContext = context;
        this.mLayout = layout;
        this.mCursor = cursor;
        this.mSnippetIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ConversationsProviderMetaData.ConversationsTableMetaData.SNIPPET);
        this.mDateIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ConversationsProviderMetaData.ConversationsTableMetaData.DATE);
        this.mMessageCount = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ConversationsProviderMetaData.ConversationsTableMetaData.MESSAGE_COUNT);
        this.mRead = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ConversationsProviderMetaData.ConversationsTableMetaData.READ);
        this.mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mLayout, parent, false);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvBody = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.body);
        holder.tvPerson = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.addr);
        holder.tvCount = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.count);
        holder.tvDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date); 
        holder.ivPhoto = (QuickContactBadge) rowView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        holder.vRead  = (View) rowView.findViewById(R.id.read);

        rowView.setTag(holder);

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

        String cBody = cursor.getString(mSnippetIndex);
        Integer cCount = cursor.getInt(mMessageCount);
        Long cDate = cursor.getLong(mDateIndex);
        Integer cRead = cursor.getInt(mRead);

        holder.tvBody.setText(cBody);

        if (cCount < 0) {
            holder.tvCount.setText("");
        } else {
            holder.tvCount.setText("(" + cCount + ")");
        }

        if (cRead == 0) {
            holder.vRead.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.vRead.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        holder.tvDate.setText(ClouUtils.getDate(context, cDate));
        holder.tvPerson.setText(cursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ConversationsProviderMetaData.ConversationsTableMetaData.CANONICAL)));
        holder.ivPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
        holder.ivPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
    // First check if it's null
    if(cursor !=null){
        // use swap to get the old cursor and close it
        Cursor oldC = conversationsListCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        if(oldC != null){
           oldC.close();
        }
       // DO NOT CLOSE THE NEW CURSOR
       // this one you must close whenever the list goes onPause(); but not before
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnx for advice. I'm too young in android. Not a solution but good advice. Tnx again.

Comment: well, I thought would solve, based on what you said "But for a first time cursor in adapter is null and it throws an a exception." You check for null before using it.

Comment: I see. So then application is started for the first time, database is empty. And as i understand my problem starts in my adapter because cursor is null - database is not created yet. My main idea was what cursorAdapter can be called like a SimpleCursorAdapter with null cursor.

Comment: well... there's no reason to create an adapter if you still do not have any data to be show on the UI. So probably you should only create it after onPostExecute returns a non-null with lenght>0 cursor.

Comment: May be i don't understand all this. When the application is started for the firs time database must be created and there is no data at this moment. But getColumnIndex must work and listView must be empty. And it works correct without AsyncTask. And didn't with it.

Comment: More simpler: app starts, create adapter with null cursor (database is not set yet), async request to database for conversations list, create databse with providers help, database is set and empty, request data, cursor not null (no data, but cursor is not null). This is was my thought.